# How to remove a page in Android CarouselView

Tags: java, android, carousel

I would like to find a simple way to not show (hide) a page in a CarouselView. Any thoughts on how to do that?

I thought mPager.removeView(View view) would do the trick but was unable to get it to work.

Here is the example code I am working with:

```
// CarouselView related variables
public static int mPages = 0;
public static int FIRST_PAGE = mPages * LOOPS / 2;

// ViewPager for CarouselView
public ViewPager mPager;

// Adapter for loading data to CarouselView
private CarouselPagerAdapter mAdapter;

/**
* Setting the CarouselView with data
*/
private void setCarouselView() {
    // Getting the number of services discovered
    mPages = ServiceDiscoveryFragment.mGattServiceData.size();
    FIRST_PAGE = mPages * LOOPS / 2;

    // Setting the adapter
    mAdapter = new CarouselPagerAdapter(getActivity(), 
                    ProfileControlFragment.this, 
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), 
                    ServiceDiscoveryFragment.mGattServiceData);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mAdapter);

    // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
    // directions left and right
    mPager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

    // mPager.removeView(); //???trying to hide page from the carousel

    // make this at least however many pages you can see
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
}
```

Anything I was able to compile would crash at run time. As you can tell, I'm new at this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [carousel library](https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view) full feature for working with carousel

Document link [here](https://github.com/alirezat775/carousel-view/wiki)

for remove item

```
carousel.remove(yourModel)
```